# How can I make this code less complicated?

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty new to VBA and I am wondering how would I simplify this code?
This code basically adds fields to the values in the pivot table.

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim SField As String

'Set Variable
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
SField = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TextFrame.Characters.Text

'Remove Existing Fields
For Each pf In pt.DataFields
If pf.Name <> "Values" Then
    pf.Orientation = xlHidden
End If
Next pf

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("2016"), "Sum of 2016", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("2017"), "Sum of 2017", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("2018"), "Sum of 2018", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("2019"), "Sum of 2019", xlSum

End Sub
```

Comment: Parameterize the year.

Comment: Or make the year a "relative reference."

Comment: ^ This. When you remove existing fields, you do so in a loop which is the ideal way to do this. When adding fields, you can apply the same logic. Just load your years into an array and loop through the array.

Comment: Assuming `ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)` is also `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")`, reuse `pt` in all these places, instead of dereferencing it 8 times more than needed.

Comment: You will be thrilled to know that there's an entire Stack site for this: [codereview.se]. Typically you get *much* more detailed insight than here on SO (SO is more aligned towards fixing specific issues, CR is all about making working code better in every possible way).

Answer (score 2):

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("2016"), "Sum of 2016", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("2017"), "Sum of 2017", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("2018"), "Sum of 2018", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("2019"), "Sum of 2019", xlSum
```

U can create a function

```
Public Sub PvSumByYear(year As String)
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields(year), "Sum of " & year, xlSum
End Sub
```

and now use

```
for i = 6 to 9
    call  PvSumByYear(Vba.cstr(2010+ i))
next i
```

Comment: You could also use a with statement to make the function easier to read `With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Dim pt As PivotTable
> Dim pf As PivotField
> Dim SField As String
> ```

Start by declaring variables not in a monolothic block at the top of the procedure, but rather as close as possible to their first use/assignment. And use spelled-out, readable identifiers that convey semantic meaning, not just their data type.

```
Dim target As PivotTable
Set target = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

RemoveExistingFields target
```

Notice `SField` is gone - it was assigned, but never referenced anywhere. Comments that say "below code does XYZ" are almost much always a missed opportunity for better abstraction:

```
Private Sub RemoveExistingFields(ByVal target As PivotTable)
    Dim currentField As PivotField
    For Each currentField In target.DataFields
        If currentField.Name <> "Values" Then currentField.Orientation = xlHidden
    Next
End Sub
```

Extracting this procedure single-handedly removed the need to declare `pf`/`currentField` in the original scope, reducing the cognitive load by that much.

Same for the second block - so the final refactored procedure might look like this:

```
Public Sub ResetPivotDataFields()

    Dim target As PivotTable
    Set target = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

    RemoveExistingFields target

    Dim currentYear As Long
    currentYear = GetCurrentYear

    AddYearDataFields target, currentYear - 3, currentYear

End Sub
```

Where `GetCurrentYear` might be as simple as this:

```
Private Function GetCurrentYear() As Long
    'TODO confirm year logic correctness (currently assumes regular calendar years)
    GetCurrentYear = Year(Date)
End Function
```

And `AddYearDataFields` might look like this:

```
Private Sub AddYearDataFields(ByVal target As PivotTable, ByVal fromYear As Long, ByVal toYear As Long)
    If fromYear > toYear Then Err.Raise 5, , "FromYear must be less than or equal to ToYear."

    Dim currentYear As Long
    For currentYear = fromYear To toYear
        target.AddDataField target.PivotFields(fieldName), "Sum of " & fieldName, xlSum
    Next
End Sub
```

Keep procedures small & specialized, name them well, and never hesitate to pass a procedure's dependencies as parameters; your code will quickly become as clear & simple as code gets. Always validate your inputs, and obsolete keywords and constructs, such as `Call` statements, always use explicit and appropriate access modifiers (don't make a procedure `Public` if it doesn't need to be; implicit default is `Public`), and pass parameters `ByVal` (implicit default is `ByRef`).